# Using href links inside <option> tag with jQuery in the way

Tags: jquery, html, href, html-select

I have the following code :

```
<div class="dropdownmenu">
    <select multiple id="cd-dropdown" name="dropdown-menu" class="cd-select">
        <option value="-1" selected>Social</option>
        <option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.twitter.com'" value="1" class="icon-monkey">Twitter</option>
        <option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.facebook.com'" value="1" class="icon-monkey">Facebook</option>
    </select>        
</div>
```

I tried adding a link inside the select box with labels, values, onclick but they all failed, I realized that the reason stands in the following jQuery code :

```
var elName = this.$el.attr( 'name' ), elId = this.$el.attr( 'id' ),
inputName = elName !== undefined ? elName : elId !== undefined ? elId : 'cd-dropdown-' + ( new Date() ).getTime();

this.inputEl = $( '<input type="hidden" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + value + '"></input>' ).insertAfter( this.selectlabel );

this.selectlabel.css( 'z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount );
this._positionOpts();
```

I couldn't figure out how to change the code in order to allow me to add links.
I thought the jQuery is the problem cause once I remove the "id="cd-dropdown" from the HTML box my links are working but the effects and designs provided by the jQuery doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$('select').change()` event :

```
$('select[name="dropdown-menu"]').change( function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == 1 ){
        //'this' refers to your select
        //insert your code to get the selected url,
        //and call "window.location.href = url"
    }
});
```

Comment: I inserted this in my jquery :<br/>
 '$('select[name="dropdown-menu"]').change( function(){ if ( $(this).val() == 1 ){ window.location.href=$(this).val(); } });' <br/>
and then called it in my html document but when I did, just like the last time, it crashed my effects from the jquery document, then i tried removing it from the jquery and to white it in the html as a <script> but took no action.